# Using TASMOTA for timeout operations

Tags: tasmota

I wish to use TASMOTA to replace my code that when triggered ( button or sensor ) to operate not as `Toggle` but staring a timeout, for example, IR sensor input triggers ON for 15 minutes.

Is is possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in [Tasmota's github](https://github.com/arendst/Tasmota/discussions/11246). Generally, using `PulseTime`